# Populating an array with user input of size not working in C#

Tags: c#

I want to let the user define the size of the array and all of the numbers inside it, so this is what I had in mind:

```
int []arr={0};
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the size of the array:");
size = Console.Read();

for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next number in the array, it's position is: " + i);
    arr[i] = Console.Read();
}
```

When I try to run it gives me an 'index out of range' error.
If someone could point what am I doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

EDIT:
After the answer I changed the code a little bit and now it looks like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the size of the array:");
input = Console.ReadLine();
size = int.Parse(input);
int[] arr = new int[size];

for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    string b;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next number in the array, it's position is: " + i);
    b = Console.ReadLine();
    arr[i] = int.Parse(b); 
}
```

So now the array can be bigger and so does the numbers inside, thanks again for the help!

Comment: The first line of your code creates an array with the length of 1. Your size variable is not used to initialize the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the array after getting input from user:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the size of the array:");
int size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //you need to parse the input too
int[] arr = new int[size];

for(int i=0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next number in the array, it's position is: " + i);
    arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //parsing to "int"
}
```

**Note:** You should not use Console.Read() it returns an ASCII of the character as **Szabolcs Dézsi** mentioned in the comments. You should use `Console.ReadLine()` instead.

Comment: `Console.Read` returns int, so you don't need to parse it. And I wouldn't recommend it to read in the size of the array, it returns the ASCII code of the character.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will correct the answer for sure.

Comment: Hey man thank for the help, I reworked the code and now it's all working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-instantiate your array object:

```
int []arr={0};
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the size of the array:");
size = Console.Read();
arr=new int[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next number in the array, it's position is: " + i);
   arr[i] = Console.Read();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not the most ideal, but this will prevent the user from entering non-numeric data. Keeps prompting each time until the data is valid.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the size of the array:");
int size;

while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out size))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the size of the array:");
}

var arr = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next number in the array, it's position is: " + i);
    int currentElement;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out currentElement))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the next number in the array, it's position is: " + i);
    }

    arr[i] = currentElement;
}
```

I would not use `Console.Read`, because with that you can only read one character at a time. So at most you can only read 0-9 for the array size, and if you enter lets say 15, the length of the array will be 1, and the next `Read` will read 5 and fill in the first element.